# I get different output when I process the code in VS2015. Is there any explanation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, nan

The code shown below was obtained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c18t6bw.aspx). But the output is somewhat different.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "The quiet NaN for type float is:  "
        << numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN()
        << endl;
    cout << "The quiet NaN for type int is:  "
        << numeric_limits<int>::quiet_NaN()
        << endl;
    cout << "The quiet NaN for type long double is:  "
        << numeric_limits<long double>::quiet_NaN()
        << endl;
}
```

This is the printout in my VS2015:

```
The quiet Nan for type float is :   nan  
The quiet Nan for type int is :   0  
The quiet Nan for type long double is :   nan
```

while the output in the MSDN article says, it should be:

```
The quiet NaN for type float is:  1.#QNAN
The quiet NaN for type int is:  0
The quiet NaN for type long double is:  1.#QNAN
```

which coincides with the values in the table shown on [this blog entry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130221-00/?p=5183).

Comment: Microsoft used to use those funky things described in the quote from MSDN. But C99 standardized what the output should be for NaN values, which is what your output shows, so it looks like Microsoft finally caught up with the C standard.

Comment: Very nice of you to answer my question. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reference article from MS doc to the change?

Comment: Change is documented here (surprisingly hard to get using google) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9e817177-0e91-48e6-b680-0531c4b26625.aspx#numeric_limits::infinity  seems outdated although mentions that it is for VS 2015 :(

Answer (score 0):

The change in the sentinel strings used by VS for these special IEEE float values is listed under "Infinity and NaN Formatting" in "Visual C++ change history 2003 - 2015" at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx

However it looks like they missed updating it in some of the VS2015 docs e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9e817177-0e91-48e6-b680-0531c4b26625.aspx ; I've submitted a correction to let them know it's not quite right.